# jquery remove text between tags

Tags: jquery

I have such html:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">2012: Ice Age</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#"> blah blah </a>
  <br>
     This text should disappear!!!
</li>
```

How to I remove that text with Jquery? I don't have a control over this code, so I cannot add any IDs for easier selection..

Comment: I think I just dropped </a> tag while pasting..

Comment: as well as the <br> tags which should be like so (in xhtml): <br />
i assume you're using xhtml....

Comment: br tags have no closing..that's what I get..

Comment: @Ben7005 is right. For XHTML, it should be <br />

Comment: Why would you assume he's using xhtml?

Comment: I get xml feed, and some js converts it to such broken HTML. I guess I should take some time and look into that script to fix broken tags..

Comment: This isn't necessarily broken, depending on your doctype.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('li').contents().last().remove();
```

If it is at the end, you can use the [`contents()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method (which gets all children, including text nodes, and the [`last()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/last/) method to target the last one.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/KtTfQ/

---

**EDIT:**

You could also just empty the content of that text node:

```
$('li br:last-child')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = '';
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/KtTfQ/2/

Answer (score 3):

It's easiest done with plain old DOM manipulation:

```
var text = $("li").get(0).lastChild;
text.parentNode.removeChild(text);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LBxqa/1/